# BF Interpreter in C++

Tags: c++, brainfuck

Need to clear my brain.

[BF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpretor in C++.

bf.h

```
#include <vector>

class BF
{
    std::vector<char>           memory;
    std::size_t                 dp;

    template<typename I>
    I findMatchingClose(I start);

    public:

        BF(std::size_t defaultMemorySize = 4096);
        void reset()            {dp = 0;}
        template<typename I>
        // Not sure how to specify that `I` is limited to allow random access.
        // Suppose I could re-write to allow slips back and forward.
        void run(I begin, I end);
};
```

bf.cpp

```
#include "bf.h"
#include <iostream>

BF::BF(std::size_t defaultMemorySize)
    : memory(defaultMemorySize, 0)
    , dp(0)
{}

template<typename I>
I BF::findMatchingClose(I loop)
{
    std::size_t openCount = 1;
    for (++loop; openCount != 0; ++loop) {
        if (*loop == '[') {
            ++openCount;
        }
        else if (*loop == ']') {
            --openCount;
        }
    }
    return loop;
}

template<typename I>
void BF::run(I begin, I end)
{

  /*
    >  Increment the data pointer by one (to point to the next cell to the right).
    <  Decrement the data pointer by one (to point to the next cell to the left).
    +  Increment the byte at the data pointer by one.
    -  Decrement the byte at the data pointer by one.
    .  Output the byte at the data pointer.
    ,  Accept one byte of input, storing its value in the byte at the data pointer.
    [  If the byte at the data pointer is zero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it forward to the command after the matching ] command.
    ]  If the byte at the data pointer is nonzero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it back to the command after the matching [ command.
  */

    std::vector<I>    stack;
    for (I loop = begin; loop != end; ++loop) {
        switch (*loop) {
            case '>':   dp = (dp + 1) % memory.size();  break;
            case '<':   dp = std::max(memory.size() -1, dp - 1); break;
            case '+':   ++memory[dp];break;
            case '-':   --memory[dp];break;
            case '.':   std::cout << memory[dp];break;
            case ',':   std::cin  >> memory[dp];break;
            case '[':   if (memory[dp]) {
                            // Enter the loop.
                            // So remember where to jump back to.
                            stack.emplace_back(loop);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Ignore the loop.
                            // So find the end (the ++loop) will take
                            // us to the next instruction.
                            loop = findMatchingClose(loop);
                        }
            case ']':   if (memory[dp]) {
                            // Next loop iteration.
                            // Set loop to start of the inner most loop.
                            // Note ++loop will take us to the first instruction.
                            loop = stack.back();
                        }
                        else {
                            // Exit the inner most loop.
                            stack.pop_back();
                        }
                        break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << (-11 % 10) << "\n";

    if (argc <= 1) {
        std::cerr << "No input file\n";
        return -1;
    }

    BF  bf;

    for (int loop = 1; loop < argc; ++loop) {
        std::ifstream   file(argv[loop]);
        std::string     program(std::istream_iterator<char>{file}, std::istream_iterator<char>{});

        bf.reset();
        bf.run(std::begin(program), std::end(program));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>     template<typename I>
>     // Not sure how to specify that `I` is limited to allow random access.
>     // Suppose I could re-write to allow slips back and forward.
>     void run(I begin, I end);
> ```

I think you're looking for

```
#include <iterator>
```

```
    template<std::random_access_iterator I>
    void run(I begin, I end);
```

That said, I'd include `<ranges>` and write

```
void run(std::ranges::random_access_range auto range);
```

---

I think that the template definitions in `bf.cpp` should be in the header file, so that they can be instantiated by client code.

---

> ```
> BF::BF(std::size_t defaultMemorySize)
> ```

Is that really a *default* size for this instance, or is it the *actual* size?  I don't see any way to change the size after this point.

---

`findMatchingClose()` is unbounded for malformed programs - there's nothing to stop `loop` reaching its matching end iterator, and causing Undefined Behaviour.

---

Is the fallthrough from `case '['` to `case ']'` intentional?  If it is, then please add `[[fallthrough]]` and a comment to explain why.

---

> ```
>         case '<':   dp = std::max(memory.size() -1, dp - 1); break;
> ```

Missing include of `<algorithm>`.  I don't think this is a very clear wraparound implementation (I only realised that `dp-1` becomes greater than `memory.size()` when `dp` is zero because of the preceding modular calculation - I'd find it clearer to have `(dp > 0 ? dp : memory.size()) - 1` or similar).

---

> ```
>                     else {
>                         // Exit the inner most loop.
>                         stack.pop_back();
> ```

I don't see any check for underflow here - needs a comment to explain why that can't happen.

---

> ```
> std::cout << (-11 % 10) << "\n";
> ```

Leftover diagnostic?

---

> ```
> if (argc <= 1) {
>     std::cerr << "No input file\n";
>     return -1;
> }
> ```

Normally, we return small *positive* values from `main()` such as `EXIT_FAILURE`.  Negative values are likely to be transformed by the runtime environment and OS; for example, POSIX [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) that

> only the least significant 8 bits (that is, `status & 0377`) shall be available from `wait()` and `waitpid()`;

But why are we failing in this case at all?  Couldn't we read from `std::cin`?  That would be a user's reasonable expectation.  (I guess the program couldn't then use the `,` command, of course.)

Comment: `Is the fallthrough from case '[' to case ']' intentional?` No. Opps.

Comment: `Leftover diagnostic?` Yes. I was checking what happened with modulo of negative values. Opps.

Comment: Thanks. Even simple programs that seem obviously correct have issues. :-)